# How to get all matching items from a array of objects in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo document like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588adde40fcbbbc341b34e1c"),
    "title" : "Fifa world cup",
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Football",
            "type" : "Sports"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "World cup",
            "type" : "Sports"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Fifa",
            "type" : "Manager"
        }
    ]
}
```

I wrote the below query to get all the tags with type `Sports` but I am only getting 1 item instead of 2

```
db.collection.find(
{ 
    tags: 
    { 
        $elemMatch: 
        { 
                type: "Sports" 
        }
    }
},
{
    "tags.$" : 1
})
```

Is it possible to get all the matching items? What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $unwind : "$tags"
},
{
    $match : {
        "tags.type" : "Sports"
    }
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        tags : {$addToSet : "$tags"}
    }
}
])
```

Comment: hmm, I could use aggregate but i am actually looking for something simple. Though i am not sure if there are other way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: `$elemMatch` projection [returns only the first matching element](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#zipcode-search), so you will have to use aggregation.